# Why there is so much neglect and even the hate of socialism/communism as the postcapitalism?

Tags: communism, socialism, capitalism, social-welfare, political-transitions

Marxism teaches that the development of technology leads to the new forms of social and economic orders. There have been already primitive communism, slavery, feudalism and now the capitalism is the main form of community and when technology development will reach new phase, then the socialism and communism will be established.

Current developments in robotics, automation, software technology, artificial intelligence and artificial general intelligence raise questions what can be done with these developments and whether people will be able to compete with machines and AI? **Do these developments enough for the phase transition from the capitalism to the postcapitalism?**

My main questions are:

- **Why people hate so much the socialism and communism as the possible future of our society?** They usually point to the failed communist states, but I usually reply that these states implemented "crude communism" (unnatural introduction of socialism and communism in society where technology have not reached necessary maturity) - form against which Marx already warned. **Why people so much hate the true socialism and communism?**
- **Why people so much neglect increased social support in societies where technology take over many jobs?** Why people is so much against increased unemployment benefits, life long education and additional support for unemployed to get new knowledge and to strive for more intellectually demanding jobs? Why people neglect that social economic phase transition in society can be quite costly from the humanitarian point of view and that social democracy can reduce those costs?

Why there is so much hatred against robotics, artificial general intelligence and society transformation that can be achieved with this?

Of course, I have only anecdotal evidence of this neglect and hatred, but this neglect and hatred forms the important trend - which can be observed in Internet comments, in unpopularity of radical left parties and decline of social democrats. So - is there sociological explanation of this trend?

Comment: I am sorry, but unfortunately we can not read the minds of the people you talked with. When you want to know why they have their opinions, you will need to ask them yourself. I think this question would just attract answers consisting of opinionated guessing, which is not the scope of this website.

Comment: I added note that I have not exhaustive sociological data about this neglect, but I have observed hints that such trend exists indeed. The question is about the explanation of this trend, which everyone experiences. Of course, the question is not about several people making several statements.

Comment: The question is normal, it just lacks the reference that people indeed neglect and hate communism, but I am not sure whether such reference is needed if the fact is self evident - e.g. in election results.

Comment: I improved question and I expect that the hold should be removed. Of course, people have beliefs and those beliefs determine their behaviors and those beliefs can be monitored, analyzed and even changed to some degree. E.g. climate change movement, movement against smoking and uncontrolled use of alcohols are examples of campaigns that tries to change beliefs and behaviors. Almost all of the political campaigns are visible examples of this. So - my question is about beliefs regarding some trend of postcapitalism. This is normal question, after modifcation.

Comment: I think you will find your answer if you rephrase the question as "Why do people not want government systems where every large-scale, real life example consists of oppressive governments, lack of freedoms and a populace kept too weak to do anything about it?"

Comment: There are many different reasons for different people. But you're asking the wrong question. The question you should ask is "what have I done to prove to people that ***This Time It's Different***?" Because ***the burden of proof is on you*** that YOUR attempt to build socialism/communism won't end up like Venezuela or North Korea or Mao's China. Merely vaguely stating "because technology improved" doesn't cut it as proof, neither is citing Marx (who had a *theory*, without any proof of its correctness or any qualitative analysis to let it be benchmarked or falsified)

Comment: You see how brainwashed population attributes the US-Empire destruction of those countries to the regimes themselves. You live in a police state with everything regulated by law. Yet, you call it "freeiest", right? Because everything is owned by important people. That's the answer. We have a ruling class and do not want the population of critical thinking (Carlin tm) because owners cannot admit that they lose their wealth when it is nationalized. You cannot have alternative system where their property is controlled by neighbours. No. That will be demonized calling justice an oppression.

Comment: This question is just way too broad. As for why people might hate communism, it's because the examples of communism they've been shown aren't examples of what people would want. In the west, it's also been vilified as a term. Socialism is a bit different in that there are plenty of good examples of it working--even within the confines of western governments, but via politics, it's also become a vilified term (though there are attempts and taking that term back from those that vilified it).